# Access element of *ngFor from component.ts

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

So I'm using the angular2-swing library and I have the following code in my template:

```
  <ul class="stack" swing-stack  [stackConfig]="stackConfig"  #myswing1 (throwout)="onThrowOut($event)">
    <li swing-card #restaurantCards [ngClass]="restaurant.restaurant" *ngFor="let restaurant of restaurants">

      <app-restaurant-card [restaurant]=restaurant.restaurant>
      </app-restaurant-card>
      <div class="overlay">
        YUM!
      </div>  
    </li>
  </ul>
```

Here is the `onThrowOut($event)` method:

```
onThrowOut(event: ThrowEvent) {

    if(event.throwDirection == Direction.RIGHT){
      this.restaurantService.addToLikes(event.target.getAttribute('ngClass'))
    }
    //make element hidden once thrown out
    event.target.setAttribute("style", "visibility: hidden; transition: .1s; ");
  }
```

However, when I try to get the attribute, it is null. Is there any way to retrieve the element from the for loop? Thanks

Comment: use `class` instead of `ngClass` in getAttributes

Comment: @david moeller, do you mean, you have to get `<li>` ?

Comment: please don't use both [tag:angularjs] and [tag:angular] tags unless your project is truly a multiple framework project.  **These are not the same framework**.

Comment: @manikantgautam I want to retrieve the element as an object though and when I try that the data that gets returned is a  string instead

Comment: Looking for the documentation, I can't find any reference to an "angular2-swipe" library on the internet... Is it perhaps "angular2-swipe**r**", in which case the library is no longer maintained?

Comment: @HereticMonkey my bad, its angular2-swing; will fix that and check the docs

Answer (score 0):

`ngClass` can be accessed `class` in DOM. Modify your code as (use `event.target.getAttribute('class')`):

```
onThrowOut(event: ThrowEvent) {

  if(event.throwDirection == Direction.RIGHT){
    this.restaurantService.addToLikes(event.target.getAttribute('class'));
  }
  ...
}
```

Also note that, now `id` would be `string` so may be you need to convert them as `number`